# Parse command line arguments and write useful usage message without additional code

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

This is more a hint than a question:
The goal is to parse a command line **and** create a useful *usage* message

code:

```
for arg ; do
  case "$arg" in
    --edit)   # edit file
              cd "$(dirname $0)" && vim "$0"
    ;;
    --noN)    # do NOT create 'NHI1/../tags'
              let noN=1
    ;;
    --noS)    # do NOT create 'HOME/src/*-latest/tags'
              let noS=1
    ;;
    --help)   # write this help message
    ;&
    *)        echo "usage: $(basename $0) options..." 1>&2
              awk '/--?\w+\)/' "$0"  1>&2
              exit
    ;;
  esac
done
```

This create the *usage* message:

```
> build_tags.bash -x
usage: build_tags.bash options...
    --edit)   # edit file
    --noN)    # do NOT create 'NHI1/../tags'
    --noS)    # do NOT create 'HOME/src/*-latest/tags'
    --help)   # write this help message
```

The clue is that the *definition* of the *case* target is also the *documentation* of the *case* target.

Comment: did you mean: `for arg;do case ${arg#-} in ...` instead of `case $1 in`...  (Note1: without double quotes, note2: `in "$@"` is implicit when you just write `for arg; do`).

Comment: Consider replacing `echo -e "usage: $(basename $0) options...\n$(awk '/--?\w+\)/' "$0")"` with `awk 'BEGIN{fname=ARGV[1]; sub(".*/","",fname); printf "usage: %s options...\n", fname} $0)} /^[[:space:]]*--?[[:alnum:]_]+)/' "$0" >&2` so it'll find the lines you want more robustly, will print the usage to stderr instead of stdout, will work in any POSIX awk instead of just GNU, doesn't rely on any particular version of `echo`, doesn't need both `basename` and `awk` reading `$0` and doesn't require a subshell for command substitution to call `awk`.

Comment: Also change `&& exit` on that line to `; exit` so it'll exit regardless of whether printing the usage message succeeded or not.

Comment: You might want to add a `--help` option to also print the usage and put the call to `awk` in a `usage()` function so it can be called there or anywhere else in your code you detect an issue that'd require usage to be printed. If it were me I'd also put some kind of comment before/after that case statement so awk only looks inside that area for the lines to print to avoid any false matches elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It seems rather pointless to continue to edit this question. If you'd like to post your solution as an answer to the duplicate, that might make sense (but check the existing answers, and avoid posting anything which resembles an older answer, as that obviously only adds noise).

Comment: add text to the *duplicate* solution **but** be aware that the clue is the *documentation* part and **not** the command-line-parsing part.

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is Question & Answer site. This doesn't seem to be a question. It is perfectly fine to post self-answered questions, but that still requires you to post a Question following the normal rules for questions, and then answering it in an Answer.